# how to use php loop inside jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to bring the data from the database in the dropdown using button with the query of append.The code is running without the loop (foreach)   but not with the loop . I also want to toggle the dropdown using jquery toggle function.The code is given below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#timetable').hide();
    $('#timeSection').click(function(){
        $(this).next('#timetable').toggle(500)
    });
    // alert('working');

    $('#addHospital').click(function() {
        var addTable = '"<select style="margin-left:65px;" name="hospital_id" id="hospital"
                            onchange="change_country(this.value)" class="frm-field ">
        <option  value="">Select Hospital:</option>

        <?php 
        if($lists['res2'] > 0) {
            foreach ($lists['res2']  as $row) {
            ?>
            <option id="hos_val" value="<?php echo $row->hos_id?>"> <?php echo $row->hos_name; ?></option>  
            <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
        </select>"';
        $('#addTbl').append(addTbl);
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you format the code to be more readable?  Also, what do you mean by "it's not running with the loop"?  What specifically isn't working?

Comment: "The code is running without the loop (foreach) but not with the loop " What does this mean??

Comment: I meant to say that Condition (if statement) and loop( foreach) are not working, if I remove them the remaining code works great that it appends dropdown and only show single entry. -@David

Comment: What is `$lists`?

Comment: it is my index name by which i am getting( retrieve ) data and set data in a array with index lists @trincot

Comment: I mean, what is it literally. Please provide sample data for it with which we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
     $(document).on('click', '#addHospital', function(){
        var addTable;
        addTable = '<select style="margin-left:65px;" name="hospital_id" id="hospital" onchange="change_country(this.value)" class="frm-field ">';
        addTable += '<option  value="">Select Hospital:</option>';

        <?php
        if($lists['res2'] > 0) 
        {
            foreach ($lists['res2']  as $row) 
            {
            ?>
            addTable += '<option id="hos_val" value="<?php echo $row->hos_id; ?>"> <?php echo $row->hos_name; ?></option>';
            <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
        addTable += '</select>';
        $('#addTbl').append(addTbl);
    });
```

If it's not working, depending on what data you are retrieving you can try $row['hos_id'] instead of $row->hos_id, same for hos_name